# Null values for all records

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064, mysql-5.7

I am writing a code for a table where 1st table is id --> auto incremented and primary key

2nd table is status --> varchar
Which i want to keep totally null
And 
Later on be changed as updated
By insert

I tried 
Example:

```
Create table justcheck ( id int auto increment primary key , status varchar(1)  IS NULL);
```

IT GAVE ME AN ERROR.

> 1064 : SYNTAX ERROR.

Comment: It should be `status varchar(1) Default NULL`; Also it seems that your status value will be integer 0,1,2 etc. You should Tinyint(1) instead of varchar(1)

Comment: Staus is for issue / returned   i tried it but won't work     Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `AUTO_INCREMENT` instead of `AUTO INCREMENT` and `IS NULL` is for check column is `null`

```
Create table justcheck ( 
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT primary key , 
    `status` varchar(1) NULL
);
INSERT INTO justcheck(status) VALUES (NULL)
```

Comment: @rick_o_master It work in sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/210219  what's your error?

Comment: @rick_o_master Ok I see try to use ` contain `status`

Comment: There is a keyword table https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html  ` can escape keyword